# How can I publish an RTSP stream to a MediaMTX instance with TLS encryption configured?

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, rtsp

I have an instance of ([MediaMTX](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx)) running on my laptop. I have an Amcrest IP camera. I can publish the camera's RTSP stream to the server so that the stream can be accessed from the MediaMTX instance.

However, I want to encrypt the stream. On the Github page for MediaMTX, they detail how TLS encryption can be enabled for incoming and outgoing RTSP streams by generating a server.key and server.crt and editing lines in the .yml configuration file. Streams can then be published and read with RTSPS and port 8322.

I have followed these steps, and set up the following path for my IP camera in the .yml:

```
###############################################
# Path settings

# Settings in "paths" are applied to specific paths, and the map key
# is the name of the path.
# Any setting in "pathDefaults" can be overridden here.
# It's possible to use regular expressions by using a tilde as prefix,
# for example "~^(test1|test2)$" will match both "test1" and "test2",
# for example "~^prefix" will match all paths that start with "prefix".
paths:

  cam1:
    source: rtsp://user:password@192.168.68.142:554
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.68.142:554 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f rtsp rtsps://localhost:8322/stream/cam1
```

But I am getting the following output from my MediaMTX instance when it runs:

```
2024/02/15 18:20:59 INF [path cam1] [RTSP source] ready: 2 tracks (H264, MPEG-4 Audio)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.168.68.142:554':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.030000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 100 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
2024/02/15 18:21:00 INF [RTSPS] [conn [::1]:60147] opened
2024/02/15 18:21:00 INF [RTSPS] [session 07a8f23e] created by [::1]:60147
2024/02/15 18:21:00 INF [RTSPS] [conn [::1]:60147] closed: path 'stream/cam1' is not configured
2024/02/15 18:21:00 INF [RTSPS] [session 07a8f23e] destroyed: not in use
[out#0/rtsp @ 00000225c75fe9c0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Server returned 400 Bad Request
Conversion failed!
2024/02/15 18:21:00 INF [path cam1] runOnInit command exited: command exited with code 3486501640
2024/02/15 18:21:29 WAR [path cam1] [RTSP source] 10 RTP packets lost
2024/02/15 18:21:33 WAR [path cam1] [RTSP source] 2 RTP packets lost
2024/02/15 18:21:39 WAR [path cam1] [RTSP source] 11 RTP packets lost
```

I have no errors and was able to publish the stream with the same path configuration (using rtsp://, not rtsps://) when using no encryption. What possible solutions can I try?